# No viable conversion between Derived Class (constructor has parameters) and Base Class (constructor is absent of parameters)

Tags: c++, constructor, interface, virtual

I have an abstract class Handle() containing a handle() method (amongst others). This class is implemented several times, with each class handling a different kind of data (stored as bytes) in a different way, e.g.

```
class BaseHandle
{
   virtual void handle(uint8_t *ptr, uint8_t data_size) = 0;
}
```

and

```
class DerivedHandleA : public BaseHandle 
{
   void handle(uint8_t *ptr, uint8_t data_size)
   {
      //DO THINGS WITH DATA OF KIND "A"
   }
}


class DerivedHandleB : public BaseHandle 
{
   void handle(uint8_t *ptr, uint8_t data_size)
   {
      //DO THINGS WITH DATA OF KIND "B"
   }
}
```

My issue is that in handling certain kinds of data the handle() method needs access to instances of other classes to call their member functions, which I would ordinarily pass through the constructor, so currently my code is like this:

```
class DerivedHandleC : BaseHandle 
{
private:
   HelperClass helper;

   void handle(uint8_t *ptr, uint8_t data_size)
   {
      //DO THINGS WITH DATA OF KIND "C" WITH FUNCTIONS FROM helper
   }

public:
   DerivedHandleC(HelperClass helper) : BaseHandle() helper(helper){};
}
```

The issue arises because I have a std::vector containing each instance of the Handler class, which is iterated through each time I get data to find the correct handler and send on the data. This works fine with DerivedHandle without parameters, but with the constructor with parameters I receive a `no viable conversion from 'DerivedHandleC' to 'BaseHandle'` when pushing it to my vector, which is understandable.

My question is, what should I be doing instead of passing the parameters I need through the constructor? I would prefer not to simply add the same parameters to all derived classes where they are not needed, though I am aware this would solve my compilation error.

---

### EDITS

Adding std::vector code on request:

Declarations

```
   typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseHandler>> HandlerVec;
   HandlerVec handlers;
```

Push back method

```
registerHandler(std::unique_ptr<BaseHandler> handler)
{
   handlers.push_back(std::move(handler));
}
```

Examples call of pushback

```
registerHandler(std::make_unique<DerivedHandleA>());
registerHandler(std::make_unique<DerivedHandleC>(helper));
```

Comment: Please show a [mre], sounds like you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing though

Comment: Can you add the code that push back into the vector, including the declaration of the vector please?

Comment: You probably want `std::vector<BaseHandle *>`. For the reasons take a look at the above lined duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses! I will have a look through your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class types declared using the `class` keyword have by default private inheritance, compared to class types declared with `struct`.

Here's an example:

```
struct A {};

struct B : A {
    // inherit publicly from A, the outside world can see the inheritance graph 
};

class C : A {
    // privately inherit, the outside world cannot see the inheritance
};
```

To inherit publicly, use a `struct` or use classes with a specifier to override the default behaviour:

```
class D : public A {
    // inherit publicly
};
```

Comment: Thank you, as it turns out specifying the public override solved my issue! (Using my example classes) I had declared DerivedHandleA and DerivedHandleB public but not DerivedHandleC, silly mistake on my part that had gone right by me!